# Make gunicorn log to sentry instead of a log file

Tags: python, django, sentry, raven

I have a Django website that uses a gunicorn startup script. It currently logs errors within a log file.

I am trying to change it to log to sentry (which I already have running and configured in settings.py)

This is the startup script

```
#!/bin/bash
  set -e
  LOGFILE=/var/log/gunicorn/myproject.log
  LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)
  NUM_WORKERS=5
  # user/group to run as
  USER=root
  GROUP=root
  cd /root/virtualenvs/myproject/myproject
  source ../bin/activate
  test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR
  exec ./manage.py run_gunicorn -w $NUM_WORKERS \
     --user=$USER -b 127.0.0.1:8080  --group=$GROUP --log-level=debug \
    --log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE
```

I have changed it to

```
#!/bin/bash
  set -e
  LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)
  NUM_WORKERS=5
  # user/group to run as
  USER=root
  GROUP=root
  cd /root/virtualenvs/myproject/myproject
  source ../bin/activate
  exec ./manage.py run_gunicorn -w $NUM_WORKERS \
     --user=$USER -b 127.0.0.1:8080  --group=$GROUP --log-level=debug
```

Which seems to cause the website to crash (Bad Gateway)

This is my settings.py logging setup:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
        },
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
            },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

I think this might have to do with the LOG LEVEL settings, but I'm not sure, any suggestions are welcome, thanks

Comment: So your web site is built with django right? if it is, what's your django version?

Comment: @glasslion Django 1.4.8

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace and exception you are seeing?  One thing I notice in the sentry configuration is that with newer versions you need class: raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler in your logger config and raven.contrib.django.raven_compat in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Where is your dsn configuration? Which version of raven?